# Oracle Apex 23 - Interactive Grid - Get all data and access them with their field name

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-23

How can i get all data (rows) and access them with their field name instead if index in Javascript.
For example (invalid code)

```
let grid = apex.region('myGridStaticID');
let data = grid.allRows;
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
//console.log(data[i][0]);
console.log(data[i].COLUMN1);
console.log(data[i].COLUMN3);
}
```

Further i find it difficult to follow the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html

for example there is a method `getViews` and i tried to call it like this which didn't work.

```
apex.region("[region static ID]").getViews();
```

It worked like this

```
apex.region("[region static ID]").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
```

Can you please explain/point out if the above line is documented as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
let igId = "region_static_id"; 
let grid = apex.region(igId).widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
let model = grid.model;
let key_COLUMN1 = model.getFieldKey("COLUMN1");
let key_COLUMN3 = model.getFieldKey("COLUMN3");
let data = [];
let grow = null;

//## Look for a better solution
model.forEach(function(row) { 
    grow = row;
    data.push(grow);
});

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
console.log(data[i][key_COLUMN1]);
console.log(data[i][key_COLUMN3]);
}
```